# Different Status types on same page

Tags: tables, data-tables, status

I have a page showing a datatable that lists two types of items, X and Y.

- X has 3 possible status; ONLINE, OFFLINE, DISABLED
- Y has 5 possible status; |, ||, |||, ||||, |||||

As an example, the table looks like this

```
STATUS       ITEM NAME
ONLINE       X1
ONLINE       X2
DISABLED     X3
OFFLINE      X4
|||          Y1
|            Y2
|||||        Y3
||||         Y4
|            Y5
||           Y6
```

**Question**: Is there a better way to show this? Looks kind of weird to have two different status types on the same table.

Comment: What are the semantics behind |, ||, |||, |||| and |||||?

Comment: Without being specific, its a sequential process with 5 possible states. | means Initialized, ||||| means Completed etc.

Comment: Given the context you just explained I think it's safe to mix the statuses but I think it's too much to ask your users to count the lines for each row. I think it would be better to name them for what they are: E.g. Step 1, step 2, etc. so that you can see which stage the Y items are at at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

From your post, it looks like X and Y should just be displayed in separate tables and Item Name should be the main column.

Unless the X's can have |, ||, etc. as possible status too and they just happened to line up in this example, they should be in separate tables.

Here's an example:

[image]

I put the explanation of the possible status under the table title but they could go beneath the tables.